# overlapping memmove best practice

Tags: c, memmove

I have a question about the 3rd parm to memmove when manipulating a string.  `strlen(string)` and `strlen(string) + 1` seem to produce the same results. I would think that the `+1` part would
include a termination `\0` but everything seems to work fine with
both.  Is there a best practice here to consider?? I've seen examples of both and I am not sure which way to go on this??

Consider the following `c` program:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <errno.h>

int main()
{
   char string1[20]="Hello World";
   char string2[20]="Hello World";
   printf("\nstring1=\"%s\"\n",string1);

   memmove(string1,string1+6,strlen(string1) + 1);

   printf("\nstring1 after memmove \"%s\" using strlen(string1) + 1\n",string1);

   printf("\nstring2=\"%s\"\n",string2);

   memmove(string2,string2+6,strlen(string2));

   printf("\nstring2 after memmove \"%s\" using strlen(sting2)\n",string2);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
string1="Hello World"

string1 after memmove "World" using strlen(string1) + 1

string2="Hello World"

string2 after memmove "World" using strlen(sting2)
```

Comment: Note that `memmove` is defined to work as if you'd used a temp buffer for storing the intermediate results, so an overlapping move is always safe with this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're starting at index `6` both `strlen(...)` and `strlen(...) + 1` are overkill and are copying extra NUL bytes past the end of the strings. It happens to work because you made oversized `char[20]` arrays so there are indeed extra NULs. Extra array slots are filled with zeros as if you'd written:

```
char string1[20] = "Hello World\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
```

You should be subtracting 6 from both. If you do that you'll see that `strlen(... + 6) + 1` or `strlen(...) + 1 - 6` are what you want. Remove the `+ 1` from either of those and it won't copy the NUL terminator, leading to a different result:

```
string1 == "World\0World\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  // with + 1, NUL copied
string2 == "World World\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"   // without + 1, NUL missing
```

Answer (score 2):

Your length logic is totally off and it's only working because the buffer is over-sized and the rest of it contains null bytes anyway. Rather than `strlen(string1)` vs `strlen(string1)+1`, it should be `strlen(string1+6)` vs `strlen(string1+6)+1`. You'll find in that case that the difference does matter, as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a string includes the terminating `'\0'` character.

Not explicitly copying that terminating character but still treating the result as a null-terminated string is undefined behavior.

There is no "best practice" here other than not relying on undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are moving extra nul bytes. The length of the right-hand side of is `strlen(string1)-6`. When you move `strlen(string1)`, you're moving an extra 6 nul bytes after the right hand side of the string, and they're there because with `char string1[20]="Hello World";`, the uninitialized bytes get initialized to `\0`.